# How to wait while browser will save data in local storage? [ReactJs]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, state

When user logs in I save his data in sessionStorage. In my home page I am checking whether sessionStorage is empty or not by using componentDidMount(). If there is no data it should redirect user to login page, otherwise continue. The problem is when in login page Log In button pressed componentDidMount() method in home page is being called before the browser saves user data in its sessionStorage (since there is no data in local storage yet, user can not be redirected to home page until he refreshes the page). How should I wait while browser will save data to sessionStorage?

## LogIn Page

```
handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post('url', { userId: e.target.elements.userId.value,
    password: e.target.elements.password.value })
    .then((response) => {
      if(response.status=200){
        this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
        let responseJSON = response;
        sessionStorage.setItem("userData", responseJSON);
      } else {
        console.log("Log In Error");
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      this.setState({ loggedIn: false });
    });
};
```

## Home Page

```
componentDidMount() {
      if( sessionStorage.getItem('userData') ){
        console.log('User Logged In');
      } else {
        this.setState({redirect: true})
      }
}
```

Comment: You should redirect on promise resolve, so do it after you set the session storage in response to AJAX

Comment: As you didn't provide the code that is actually making the trouble. According to my assumptions You must have been redirecting to the Homepage without getting the response from the API call, which eventually calls HomePage's componentDidMount without any proper response from the API.
You might have to provide the complete code, where you are actually doing the call.

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

You can bind and event listener on the web storage inside your `componentDidMount` method.

Keep in mind this only works for changes happened within the same tab or frame.

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function (e) {
  if (e.storageArea === sessionStorage) {
    // handle change here
  }
});
```